# How to extract Email addresses from My Gmail Account

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gmail, extractor

I am **looking for script or a way to extract** all the email addresses of all the recipients from my gmail account.

Please Help..!!

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do and which technology you want.

Answer (score 0):

From contacts.google.com you can export all your contacts (even non saved) to a csv